# Websocket Unit test : WS from ScalaTestRouteTest doesnt do a websocket request

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to put in place a unit test for websocket. From the [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/websocket-support.html#server-side-websocket-support-scala), I should be able to use `WS`

See below a sscce

```
package com.streamingout

import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatchers.Rest
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.{ScalatestRouteTest, WSProbe}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}


class Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest{


  //--------------- Flow ---------------
  def flow = {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._
    val source =  Source.tick(initialDelay = 0 second, interval = 1 second, tick = TextMessage("tick"))

    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, source)
  }


  //-------------- Routing ------------
  def route = {
    path("/wskt") {
      println("websocket ws")
      handleWebSocketMessages(flow)
    } ~
      path(Rest) { pathRest =>
        println("path Rest")
        getFromFile(s"webapp/$pathRest")
      }
  }


  // create a testing probe representing the client-side
  val wsClient = WSProbe()

  // WS creates a WebSocket request for testing
  WS("/wskt", wsClient.flow) ~> route ~> check {
    // check response for WS Upgrade headers
    isWebSocketUpgrade shouldEqual true

  }
}
```

When I run the test, I can see in my console the `path Rest` message, meaning that `WS` doesnt upgrade to Websocket.

Anyone knows what is wrong with my code?

I am using akka 2.4.7

Thank you

Comment: Commenting on one assumption you are having in the question. The `println`s in the code don't necessarily get run at runtime. At least the first one runs (once) at route declaration time. The second one I am not sure - it depends. Some directives cause the inner route to be evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the above code work, in the `route`, the path `/wkst` should be without any leading slash

```
def route = {
    path("wskt") {
      println("websocket ws")
      handleWebSocketMessages(flow)
    } ~
      path(Rest) { pathRest =>
        println("path Rest")
        getFromFile(s"webapp/$pathRest")
      }
  }
```